# Open jupyter in firefox window with no decorations

Tags: python, firefox, julia, jupyter

I am using Jupyter in Firefox on OSX. Is there a way I can ensure the notebook opens in a window without any of the toolbars etc of firefox?
I currently use it for julia by running

```
using IJulia
notebook()
```

but I guess the kernel should not matter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be useful (untested):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1029353

By the way, you can launch the notebook directly from the terminal using

```
ipython notebook   # IPython version < 4
```

or

```
jupyter notebook   # Jupyter version >= 4
```

[ 
or

```
ipython notebook --profile julia
```

if you are running IPython < 3, in which case I recommend upgrading
]

Also note that in Chrome there is a nice mode with the toolbars hidden via 
`View -> Enter Presentation Mode`
(I do not see anything like this in Firefox.)

You can then manually hide the IPython/Jupyter headers with `View->Hide toolbar` and `View->Hide header` from within the IPython/Jupyter menu.
In this way you can get the whole screen dedicated to your notebook with (almost) no visual clutter.

Comment: You should summarise any links to guard against link rot.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, this was really useful. The link you posted was to a dead extension, but I did manage to find three other extensions that did it: 'Hide tab pane with one tab', 'Hide BookmarksBar' and 'Hide Navigation Bar'. I don't want to succumb to google's mega-capitalism when there is a great open-source alternative :-)
And thanks for the hint on jupyter notebook!